# Getting "The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel"

Tags: c#, postman, access-token

I got this code from Postman and I am trying to execute the same on VS studio but getting exception message as "The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel"

```
var client = new RestClient("https://196.189.148.28/bw_auth_server/oauth2/token");

client.Timeout = -1;

var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");

request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic SOMEBASE64STRING==");

request.AddHeader("Cookie", "SESSION=M2ViZDVlZWEtOTU3Yy00MGYzLWE0MzUtYWZkMzJjNWFiNzc5");

request.AddParameter("grant_type", "client_credentials");

request.AddParameter("scope", "client");

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

Comment: Does the server have an SSL certificate that is trusted by the machine the code is running on? (If you visit `https://192.189.148.28` does your browser tell you that the certificate is valid?)

Comment: @Paresha: you shouldn't past your base 64 encoded password there; everybody can read it.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar Nope, not getting any kind of message or warning on browser about certificate.

Comment: What is your question?  TLS is automatically performed before REQUEST is sent and does encryption. REQUEST does not know that the connection was never established since it happens before the request is ever sent. TLS is also done before the AUTH is done.  Postman does the TLS different than inside c#. TLS uses a certificate and since connection works with Postman you do not have a certificate issue. The best way of passing TLS is to make sure you use Net 4.7.2 or later that uses operating system to perform TLS and use default option which is OS.   Code is probably using older version of Net.

Comment: Highly unlikely that the server has a certificate for the IP address, I suggest you check what certificate it has. Clearly something is going wrong with the SSL connection Maybe use Wireshark to get a trace?